# Convert a String to an integer array

Tags: arrays, string, arduino

I have an ESP8266 (Arduino) that receives a string (as per the Arduino `String` class library) of 20 numbers ranging from 0 to 200, comma delimited.

I would like to parse and place the values into an array of integers (e.g. int IntArray[21];. This is what the String looks like:

```
dataFromClient = "1,2,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,25,125,0,175,100,0,25,175,0,50,125";
```

I have tried numerous times for the past 2 weeks and I keep getting into "string" hell! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: chrisI, thanks so much!!  This works perfectly.  I was down the path of trying to use char strings, strtok, etc.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should give more details about what you have tried so far.

Since you are using the Arduino libraries you can use the toInt() member function of the string class.

```cpp
unsigned int data_num = 0;
int data[21];
// loop as long as a comma is found in the string
while(dataFromClient.indexOf(",")!=-1){
  // take the substring from the start to the first occurence of a comma, convert it to int and save it in the array
  data[ data_num ] = dataFromClient.substring(0,dataFromClient.indexOf(",")).toInt();
  data_num++; // increment our data counter
  //cut the data string after the first occurence of a comma
  dataFromClient = dataFromClient.substring(dataFromClient.indexOf(",")+1);
}
// get the last value out of the string, which as no more commas in it
data[ data_num ] = dataFromClient.toInt();
```

In this code the string is consumed until only the last value is left in the string. If you want to persist the data in the string you can define a position variable as the substring start point and updating it on every loop cycle to the position after the next comma

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer. Thank you